# How to make ffmpeg works?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I installed ffmpeg and used this library but when i use this $video = $ffmpeg->open('/var/media/video.mp4');
I got below error. please let me know what we have to do

Fatal error: Uncaught Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffprobe failed to execute command '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe' '-help' '-loglevel' 'quiet': Error Output: /usr/local/bin/ffprobe: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0) /usr/local/bin/ffprobe: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0) /usr/local/bin/ffprobe: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5) /usr/local/bin/ffprobe: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5) /usr/local/bin/ffprobe: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5) /usr/local/bin/ffprobe: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librubberband.so. in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/vendor/aminyazdanpanah/php-ffmpeg-video-streaming/src/FFMpeg.php on line 51